# kubernetes nginx ingress rewrite conflict on url

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, url-rewriting, kubernetes-ingress

I have add rewrite rules in kubernetes nginx ingress with following annotation.

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet:
    rewrite /v3/admin/registration(.*) /v2/admin/registration$1 break;
spec:
  rules:
- host: example.com
  http:
    paths:
      - path: /v2/(customer|admin|login)($|\?|/)
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: 
            port:
              number: 80
```

Now new path has been added to my app. this new path has following url
example.com/v3/admin/(registration)/[^/]*/(status) for this url i want to pass it to another service. how to achieve this ?? as this new url will conflict with rewrite rule.

Comment: rewrite has v3, the new path is v4 where is the conflict?

Comment: @RakeshGupta both has v3. i have write v3 by mistake.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that your rewrite rules work separately, and the question is how to make them work perfectly together?